# NSPathControl problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspathcontrol

I have an application I'm developing in cocoa, and I have a problem with `NSPathControl`.

I set the style of the control to `Popup`, and when I launch my App and click on the path control, it shows me a popup menu with the components of the URL I set. I.e., for URL like `file://localhost/Applications/Games/` it shows me the following: `My Macbook`, `Macintosh HD`, `Applications`, `Games`.

Now, when I click on `Applications`, I receive an action, and whithin that action `[[sender clickedPathComponentCell] URL]` returns correct URL: `file://localhost/Applications/`.

Problem 1:
 But when I click on `Macintosh HD`, I get an URL with double trailing slash: `file://localhost//`.

Problem 2: is that I get the same URL `file://localhost//` when I click on `My Macbook` item. So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why does the URL to `Macintosh HD` ends with double slash?
2. How can I distinguish clicks on `Macintosh HD` and `My Macbook`, and what is the correct URL to `My Macbook`, where Finder shows the list of mounted volumes (on my macbook it is `Macintosh HD` and `BOOTCAMP`)?

I've examined the tutorial named "SourceView", but there was no item like `My Macbook`, so I was not able to find out, whether `My Macbook` is really exists as a some kind of virtual folder, or I should just use `NSFileManager` to get the list of mounted volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1:

The URL is `file://localhost//` because the path to your boot volume is `/`. It's a bit odd, but `file://localhost/` (single slash) would mean "a file on localhost with no path", so you get `file://localhost//` (double slash) to mean "a file on localhost at path `/`.

You shouldn't really have to worry about the eccentricities of the URL you're getting - just pass it along to whatever needs it and it should deal with it just fine.

Problem #2:

"My MacBook" doesn't really exist - it's a virtual folder that shows the list of connected volumes, `/Network`, etc. There's isn't a valid path for it since it doesn't exist, so instead you get the path to your boot volume instead.

Comment: >The URL is file://localhost// because the path to your boot volume is /.
Yeah, I thought about that, but what I do not understand, is why then URL to, say, Applications folder do not have double slash after localhost and just looks normally like file://localhost/Applications/, not file://localhost//Applications/

Comment: And about #2, I'm still interested in how to distinguish clicks on "Macintosh HD" and "My Macbook" within NSPathControl.

And thank you very much for answering)

Comment: It should be noted that if the path set on NSPathControl begins with a double slash "//", it will show "Macintosh HD  > Users > Username > Example Directory". If the path begins with a single slash "/" it will show "Username > Example Directory". This question and answer helped me figure that out, I didn't see it documented anywhere else.